# Reuse MongoDB connection in Azure Functions

Tags: java, mongodb, azure-functions

In order to avoid performance issues when connecting to databases, Azure Function documentation suggests that we reuse database connections. How to reuse a MongoDB connection in Java so that the connection is reused for multiple function invocations?

Comment: Can you provide reference documentation where they have suggested to reuse database connection when used from Azure Functions. BTW have you implemented DB connection reuse? I posted this question @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67207199/how-to-reuse-database-connection-in-azure-functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best option is outside of the function method (e.g. `public static void Run()` or whatever), creating the connection as a static that can be reused without having to create a new connection each request.  Function instances are kept around and re-used, and so would the connection

Below is pseudo-code (I don’t know actual MongoDb SDK, but pattern should work great)

```
package com.hollan.com

// ...

private static MongoDbConnection _mongoConnection = new MongoDbConnection(“http://myMongo:1234”);

public void MyFunction(...) {
  _mongoConnection.Insert(...);
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error while adding my connection: _Syntax error on tokens, AnnotationName expected instead_ with code `public static MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(<connection string>);` when I put this line outside the class