# MongoDB static connection error: Syntax error on tokens, AnnotationName expected instead

Tags: java, mongodb, azure-functions

I am using Azure Functions to connect to a database in Java. To reuse connections, static connections are needed. But I am getting:
*Syntax error on tokens, AnnotationName expected instead*

How to get a static connection in java?
Here is my code:

```
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import org.bson.Document;

import org.json.JSONObject;
private static MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(<Connection-String>);

public class DBClass{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, your code just worked fine.

```
package com.mongofunction;

import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoIterable;

import java.util.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.*;

public class Function {

    private static String connectionString = "mongodb://jackmongo:euGe2******Lg==@jackmongo.documents.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb";
    private static final MongoClient client = MongoClients.create(connectionString);

    @FunctionName("HttpTrigger-Java")
    public HttpResponseMessage run(
            @HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {HttpMethod.GET}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
            final ExecutionContext context) {
        context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");

        String result = "";

        result += client.toString() + " : " + client.hashCode() + '\n';

        MongoIterable<String> dbList = client.listDatabaseNames();

        for(String db : dbList){
            context.getLogger().info(db);
            result += db + '\n';
        }
        return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body(result).build();
    }
}
```

My function app url: https://jackjavafunction.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger-Java

The response:

[image]

Could you please have a check with your mongo-java-driver version? Here is mine:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

---

### Update

DBClass.java

```
public class DBClass{
    private static String connectionString = "mongodb://jackmongo:euGe****g==@jackmongo.documents.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb";
    private static final MongoClient client = MongoClients.create(connectionString);

    public static String GetDBs(){
        String result = "";

        result += client.toString() + " : " + client.hashCode() + '\n';

        MongoIterable<String> dbList = client.listDatabaseNames();

        for(String db : dbList){
            result += db + '\n';
        }

        return result;
    } 

}
```

Function.java

```
public class Function {

    @FunctionName("HttpTrigger-Java")
    public HttpResponseMessage run(
            @HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {HttpMethod.GET}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
            final ExecutionContext context) {
        context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");
        return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body(DBClass.GetDBs()).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: My issue is when I wanted to reuse the connection. To do that, I tried to declare the  Mongo client outside the class, like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57991520/reuse-mongodb-connection-in-azure-functions). This is when I'm getting the above-mentioned error.

Comment: Based on my knowledge, this will not cause any difference. However, I did as yours, and got a success. Check the update.