# How to reuse Cosmos DB connection in Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, microservices, azure-cosmosdb

I am using Azure Cosmos DB service. I have many azure functions which read & write data to this database (Kind of microservices architecture). Depending on the ingest, these functions scale to many instances and try persisting the data in parallel.

Inside these functions, I am connecting to the database and then performing Read/Write
`MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, client)`

As my current implementation calls this "connect" function to the database every time (On invoking the function), is that OK. As CosmosDB service provide a function to set connection pool size, I think it is already maintaining set of connections. So my question is, whenever I call connect, will it return one of the available connections from the pool or "connect" actually makes a new connection to the database?

Note: I'm aware that in traditional Web application, We can use 'Singleton' or "Database Connection Pool', So that we can reuse 'mongoClient' objects for any CRUD Operations, However in Serverless architectures, How to reuse mongoClient Objects by many function invocations

Comment: You'd do it as you would in any WebAPI project. Azure Functions don't shut down between requests (unless they are idle for a certain amount of time). Typically you'd inject a singleton in to your DI pipeline and that singleton would maintain the connection object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure function support for connection pooling or any other way to reuse same instance of db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66795247/azure-function-support-for-connection-pooling-or-any-other-way-to-reuse-same-ins)

Comment: Thank you @Andy, I will try

Comment: Thank you @ChristianVorhemus, I think this works within a function and not across. Will check it